# TinyMCE and bootstrap conflict

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce, normalize

I use tinyMCE editor to edit article content on my site and bootstrap.css to styling content.
When I do that in Internet Explorer, I have some troubles.
TinyMCE resizes images by native browser method which sets width and height attributes. But Bootstrap uses normalize.css, which resets image width and height and breaks width and height attributes in IE.
What can I do to avoid this? I need convert attribute to styles before submit article content to server, but insertion handler on [getContent event](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onGetContent) doesn't help

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I believe I am encountering the same issue.